# How can I change the font family of tip labels in a phylogenetic tree in R ape package when saving to devSVG?

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I have several phylogenetic trees imported into `R` from Newick format. I am using the `ape` package to plot the trees with `plot.phylo` command. I would like to be able to change the font family (not only the size, which I can do with `cex`, or color with `col`) of the tip labels to *monospace*. The `plot` command does take `family` argument, but nothing happens when I pass `family="mono"`. I tried including it in `par` with no success either.

```
library(ape)
tr <- rtree(10)
plot(tr)
```

gives me the same as

```
plot(tr, family="mono")
```

And I would like to see a change in font.

EDIT: The font-family specification seems to work when saving graphic to `png`, but not `devSVG`. How can I save updated font to `SVG`?

Comment: Which documentation are you looking at? You should be looking at `?plot.phylo` rather than `?plot` ... if you don't have luck here you might try the r-sig-phylo <at> r-project.org mailing list ...

Comment: I searched both. None have any parameters to change font family/face. But it seems you can pass any graphical parameters (thanks to  `... =`). Also, `family` works for regular plots (scatterplots, etc), but not for trees. Thanks for the mailing list recommendation!

Comment: unfortunately, the fact that you can pass a parameter in the `...` slot doesn't necessarily mean that the function will do anything useful with it ...

Comment: that's exactly how it looks - for an object of class `phylo` it does nothing :/

Comment: looks like you may have gotten your answer via the `tiplabels` command, on r-sig-phylo.  If you want to write that up as an answer here, you're allowed (encouraged) to answer your own questions so that future searchers will find the answer ...

Comment: unfortunately, `tiplabels` does not help either. it works in simple examples, but it doesn't work for my tree. It may be that the font gets "lost" somewhere on its way to `SVG` format. I can't view it normally in X11() because the labels overlap and I just see a black mess.

Comment: ok, so I can confirm that the problem is with `devSVG`. If I set `family="mono"` in `par` and save the tree to a `png`, I can see the Courier New font. The problem remains, though: how Do I change the font and save to `SVG`? I'll refine my question to reflect device dependency.

Comment: try `svg` in the `Cairo` package instead ... ?  (I can confirm that it works for a trivial example.)

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I have tried and it worked - I am just not allowed to post my own answer for another hour ;) I have it typed in and ready to be posted!

Comment: and actually, it's weird, but `Cairo` and `cairo` are two different packages, and `svg` sits in `cairo` under `grDevices`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, a success!

In order to be able to manipulate font-family when saving graphics in `SVG` format, I had to use the package `grDevices` and method `cairo`:

```
library(cairo)
svg(filename = file, width = width, height = height, family = "mono")
```

which allows setting the `family` argument.

For future reference, what did **NOT** work was:

`devSVG(file, width, height)` and then setting `family` in `par` or `plot`,

and
`Cairo(file, width, height, type="svg")` with `family` in `par` or `plot`